# Connecting to MonetDB server on guest virtual machine from host

Tags: virtualbox, monetdb

I have a virtual machine (centos 7) in VirtualBox on a RHEL 5 host running MonetDB5 (server v 11.19.9). I can connect to the database from with the guest through both jdbc and mclient. However, I cannot connect to it from the host.

I have port 50000 forwarded to port 5555, and have set shared=yes in monetdb and control=yes on monetdbd. When I try to connect using

```
java -jar jdbcclient.jar -dmydatabase -umonetdb -hlocalhost -p5555 -Xdebug
```

I type in my password and it waits a long time, then says:

```
Database connect failed: Unable to connect (localhost:5555): Connection to server lost!
```

The javaclient log file is unhelpful:

```
RD 1438806937222: server closed the connection (EOF)
```

The merovingian.log file is also unhelpful since nothing is added to it. Note that the mserver command in the log says --set-mapi_open=false, even though I have set sharing and control = yes. But I can't find the MonetDB.conf file so I don't know where to change "mapi_open=true." I tried making my own MonetDB.conf file and putting it in /etc/ but it doesn't seem to work there.

Note that I can connect to the machine with

```
ssh me@localhost -p222 -X
```

where I have forwarded port 20 to 222, so I feel good about the port forwarding. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the firewall. Even though port 22 (ssh) was automatically opened on the guest machine, port 50000 needed to be configured manually.